# Objective C get the old location in NSARRAY

Tags: objective-c, core-location

```
method - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

Since this method got deprecated I was wondering how you can access the old location in the NSArray. Does the Array store the location each update. I tried the below way but couldnt get it to update

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
    CLLocation *oldLocation;
    NSNumber *lat = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.latitude];
    NSNumber *lon = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.longitude];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:counter forKey:@"counter"];
    NSDictionary *userLocation=@{@"lat":lat,@"long":lon};

    [defaults setObject:userLocation forKey:@"userLocation"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    if (locations.count > 1) {
        oldLocation = locations[locations.count - 2];
    }


    NSLog(@"old location(%f,%f)", oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, oldLocation.coordinate.longitude );
//      NSLog(@"new location (%f,%f)", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` returns a list of locations that you haven't seen yet. It may batch together several updates into a single notification. But it doesn't send you data you've already received. If you want to keep track of previous locations that you've already received, you need to store those yourself.

Comment: how would I keep track?

Comment: When locations come in, store them. Where depends on your data model and needs. In a property, Core Data, NSUserDefaults, local files, your server, whatever your product uses to store its data.

Comment: my problem is that oldLocation = [locations lastObject]; will just keep updating the location to be the latest not the old

Comment: Right. You will need to store `oldLocation` somewhere persistent. Where you store it is up to you. The system doesn't send you any old location information. It's up to you to store it if you need it. It looks like you're storing it in `NSUserDefaults`. So if you need the old location information, you can read it from there before you store it.

Answer (score 0):

I did this using an NSMutableArray that I call locHistory, like this:

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
   [locHistory addObject:locationManager.location];
   if ([locHistory count] > 2) {
    [locHistory removeObjectAtIndex:0];
   }
//more code...
}
```

For some reason it wouldn't work with [locations lastObject] so instead I add locationManager.location to the array. I initialise the NSMutableArray elsewhere with initWithCapacity:2 which could be 1 since it will just expand it. Every time it updates the location I add the new location and remove first element when the amount of elements exceeds 2. What remains after that is your old location at index 0 and your latest at index 1. Maybe there is a better way to it, but this works for me.